# INSERT INTO query only if record doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

In my table I have two fields: `v_id` and `ip_address`. I want to insert some data into this table only if the IP address doesn't already exist.

After Google'ing I came across the `INSERT IGNORE INTO` statement, and this is my code:

```
public function update_visits($ip_address)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `24h_visits` (ip_address) VALUES (?)';
    if($this->db->query($sql, array($ip_address)))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

It runs fine and without errors, but duplicate rows are still being made, even if the same IP is passed in as a parameter.

Anyone got a clue? Thanks.

Comment: Is ip_address the primary key on the table?

Comment: perhaps you could use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a `UNIQUE` index on `ip_address` for `INSERT IGNORE` to work:

```
ALTER TABLE 24h_visits
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX(ip_address)
```

**However**, I haven't seen the entirety of your schema, but I would assume that there's a column that stores a timestamp of the last visit. It's the only way this would make sense (so you can purge visits older than 24 hours every now and then).

In this case, you actually don't want `INSERT IGNORE`, but [`INSERT  ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead. Assuming you have a column called `last_visit`:

```
INSERT INTO 24h_visits (ip_address, last_visit)
   VALUES ('$ip_address', NOW())
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_visit = NOW();
```

With `INSERT IGNORE`, the new row is never inserted, and thus you would always have the first value ever inserted on `last_visit`, which (the way I see it) is not entirely correct.

Comment: +1 `UNIQUE` constraint is the best way. Enforce the integrity in the database where you can.

Comment: @alex: you're so DBAish today :-)

Comment: @zerkms A different day, a different hat :D

Answer (score 5):

Add the `UNIQUE` constraint to your `ip_address` column.

Then your query would fail if it attempts to add a duplicate `ip_address` row (unless you use `INSERT IGNORE`).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers don't actually answer the question: Creating a unique index *prevents* the duplicate from being inserted, which is a good idea, but it doesn't answer "how to insert if not already there".
This is how you do it:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 24h_visits (ip_address)
select ?
where not exists (select * from 24h_visits where ip_address = ?)
```

Additionally, this approach does not require any changes to schema.

Comment: I tried to answer the question with not what was asked, but what I believe the OP actually wants.

Comment: I was chiding your initial answer to *just* put a unique index, which I think is a terrible idea - then you have to handle exceptions etc during normal processing. Sure put the index, but you wan't to *avoid* exceptions